# Use Maven to get documentation for dependency for Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, log4j

I have `log4j` library in Eclipse Maven Java project:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>caen</groupId>
        <artifactId>CAENRFIDLibrary</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I would like to ask Maven to get documentation for `log4j` in order Eclipse could give me more info in editor window. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse you can mark the project with log4j as a dependency, right click, press Maven in the upcoming menu, then click on Download JAVADOC. That should be it